# Passing a global value to DateTemplate in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

I have the following ListView with a DataTemplate that creates three TextBlocks and populates each entry with the data from class `Item`.

I want to set the width of each TextBlock to some value that is passed through with the `ICollection<Item>` array as a value that is the same for each entry. With the syntax below, each `Item` would have to have the values of GlobalWidth1, etc to be set for each instance.

Is there any way to pass the width values as a global values for the entire `ICollection<Item>` collection in WPF?

```
<ListView>
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <WrapPanel>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Data1}" Width="{Binding GlobalWidth1}" />
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Data2}" Width="{Binding GlobalWidth2}" />
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Data3}" Width="{Binding GlobalWidth3}" />
            </WrapPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

```
public class Item
    {
        public string Data1 { get; set; }

        public string Data2 { get; set; }

        public string Data3 { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: You mean `ICollection<Item>`?

Comment: @Clemens  thanks for catching that. Fixed.

Comment: GlobalWidth1/2/3 could be properties of the view model. You would bind them like `Width="{Binding DataContext.GlobalWidth1, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ItemsControl}}"`

Comment: Maybe you can create your own property GlobalWidth and bind it to that ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using bindings you could define resource values within the `XAML` file itself and use `{StaticResource ...}`.

```
xmlns:system="clr-namespace:System;assembly=System.Runtime"
...
<ListView>
   <ListView.Resources>
       <system:Double
           x:Key="GlobalWidth1">
           100
       </system:Double>
       <system:Double
           x:Key="GlobalWidth2">
           120
       </system:Double>
       <system:Double
           x:Key="GlobalWidth3">
           150
       </system:Double>
   </ListView.Resources>
   <ListView.ItemTemplate>
       <DataTemplate>
           <WrapPanel>
               <TextBlock Text="{Binding Data1}" Width="{StaticResource GlobalWidth1}" />
               <TextBlock Text="{Binding Data2}" Width="{StaticResource GlobalWidth2}" />
               <TextBlock Text="{Binding Data3}" Width="{StaticResource GlobalWidth3}" />
           </WrapPanel>
       </DataTemplate>
   </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

You could even have these defined in your top level `App.Resources` and set them from the `App.xaml.cs`.

Note: If you add these to the `App.Resources` you will need to remove them from the local `ListView.Resources`

```
    public App()
    {
        //hardcode

        this.Resources.Add("GlobalWidth1", 100);
        this.Resources.Add("GlobalWidth2", 120);
        this.Resources.Add("GlobalWidth3", 150);

        //or perhaps define them in the global settings
        this.Resources.Add("GlobalWidth1", Settings.Default.GlobalWidth1);
        this.Resources.Add("GlobalWidth2", Settings.Default.GlobalWidth2);
        this.Resources.Add("GlobalWidth3", Settings.Default.GlobalWidth3);
    }
```

[image]

Of course if you want to keep it using bindings you can just add static properties on the `Item` class:

```
public class Item
{
    public string Data1 { get; set; }

    public string Data2 { get; set; }

    public string Data3 { get; set; }

    public static double GlobalWidth1 => 100;
    public static double GlobalWidth2 => 120;
    public static double GlobalWidth3 => 150;
}
```

I would personally recommend keeping it in the `XAML` for I find it more organized to keep pure UI code in the `View` layer and out of the `ViewModel` layer  (If you are sticking to MVVM)

Comment: This did the trick in terms of getting the value set. However, the only think I'm unsure of is how to set these values dynamically from C#. I tried ```ListViewControl1.Resources["GlobalWidth1"] = 50```, but the value is not set before ItemsSource is set.

Comment: Your sample has StatusResource. I skimmed over it too fast. I changed it to DynamicResource to make it work. Thanks for much.